# How to check if a string contains an int? -Swift

Tags: string, swift, keyboard, int, contains

I need to know if a string contains an Int to be sure that a name the user entered is a valid full name,
for that I need to either make the user type only chars, or valid that there are no ints in the string the user entered.
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Convert to `NSString` and you can use `string.containsString(otherString)` and just check if it contains a number.

Comment: Why check only for integers? Would ➽, ⨕,  , or  be valid characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651612/how-do-i-check-uitextfield-values-for-specific-types-of-characters-e-g-letters.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use Foundation methods with Swift strings, and that's what you should do here. `NSString` has built in methods that use `NSCharacterSet` to check if certain types of characters are present. This translates nicely to Swift:

```
var str = "Hello, playground1"

let decimalCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits

let decimalRange = str.rangeOfCharacter(from: decimalCharacters)

if decimalRange != nil {
    print("Numbers found")
}
```

If you're interested in restricting what can be typed, you should implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and the method `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` to prevent people from typing those characters in the first place.

Comment: Swift 3,     let str = "Hello, playground1"
        let decimalCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits
        let decimalRange = str.rangeOfCharacter(from: decimalCharacters, options: String.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
        if decimalRange != nil {
            print("Numbers found")
        }

Answer (score 24):

Simple **Swift 4** version using `rangeOfCharacter` method from `String` class:

```
    let numbersRange = stringValue.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits)
    let hasNumbers = (numbersRange != nil)
```

Answer (score 8):

This method is what i use now for checking if a string contains a number

```
func doStringContainsNumber( _string : String) -> Bool{

        let numberRegEx  = ".*[0-9]+.*"
        let testCase = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", numberRegEx)
        let containsNumber = testCase.evaluateWithObject(_string)

        return containsNumber
        }
```

If your string Contains a number it will return true else false. Hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

```
//A function that checks if a string has any numbers
func stringHasNumber(_ string:String) -> Bool {
    for character in string{
        if character.isNumber{
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

/// Check stringHasNumber function
stringHasNumber("mhhhldiddld")
stringHasNumber("kjkdjd99900")
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the explanation/details
of the answer here and provide justification.

Answer (score 4):

```
        //Swift 3.0 to check if String contains numbers (decimal digits):


    let someString = "string 1"
    let numberCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits

    if someString.rangeOfCharacter(from: numberCharacters) != nil
    { print("String contains numbers")}
    else if someString.rangeOfCharacter(from: numberCharacters) == nil
    { print("String doesn't contains numbers")}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ContainsNumbers(str).count > 0)
{
    // Your string contains at least one number 0-9
}

func ContainsNumbers(s: String) -> [Character]
{
    return s.characters.filter { ("0"..."9").contains($0)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.3. version working.

```
extension String
{
    func containsNumbers() -> Bool
    {
        let numberRegEx  = ".*[0-9]+.*"
        let testCase     = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", numberRegEx)
        return testCase.evaluateWithObject(self)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//guard let firstname = textField.text else { return }
    let testStr1 = "lalalala"
    let testStr2 = "1lalalala"
    let testStr3 = "lal2lsd2l"

    print("Test 1 = \(testStr1.containsNumbers())\nTest 2 = \(testStr2.containsNumbers())\nTest 3 = \(testStr3.containsNumbers())\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trick Swift into using Regex by wrapping up its nsRegularExpression

```
class Regex {
  let internalExpression: NSRegularExpression
  let pattern: String

  init(_ pattern: String) {
    self.pattern = pattern
    var error: NSError?
    self.internalExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
  }

  func test(input: String) -> Bool {
    let matches = self.internalExpression.matchesInString(input, options: nil, range:NSMakeRange(0, countElements(input)))
    return matches.count > 0
  }
```

}

```
if Regex("\\d/").test("John 2 Smith") {
  println("has a number in the name")
}
```

I got these from http://benscheirman.com/2014/06/regex-in-swift/

Comment: The question was about the *Swift* programming language, not about JavaScript. Btw, there are more letters than a-z, A-Z. What about Ä or é ?

Comment: While this answers the question of locating digits in a string, perhaps it might be better to check if all characters in the string are valid (i.e., word chars or spaces) using the regex "^[\\w\\s]+$"

Answer (score 0):

```
let numericCharSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "1234567890")

let newCharSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "~`@#$%^&*(){}[]<>?")

let sentence = "Tes#ting4 @Charact2er1Seqt"

if sentence.rangeOfCharacter(from: numericCharSet) != nil {
    print("Yes It,Have a Numeric")
    let removedSpl = sentence.components(separatedBy: newCharSet).joined()
    print(sentence.components(separatedBy: newCharSet).joined())
    print(removedSpl.components(separatedBy: numericCharSet).joined())
} 

else {
    print("No")
}
```